# Return array of rows in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Got the following tables:

```
forms
- id
- name

questions
- id
- form_id
- type
- name

questions_translations
- id
- question_id
- lang_id
- label
- placeholder

poss_answers
- id
- question_id
- lang_id

poss_answers_translations
- id
- poss_answer_id
- value
```

Now I want to select all the questions and possible answers from 1 form, from 1 language. I can easily select all the elements without using the poss_answers_table:

```
SELECT b.*, f.* FROM app_questions q JOIN app_questions_translations qt  ON q.form_id = 4 WHERE lang_id = 4 && qt.question_id = q.id
```

This gets me all the elements for the two tables, but now I want to add in the poss_answers table. This table holds all the possible answers for a select field, or a checkbox field, or radio field. These are the answers which can be choosen from.

But how can I do that within 1 query?

Comment: Just join the poss_answers table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that 1 question (row) has many answers (rows), joining to the answer table will give you the question details returned for every answer row.  This is not ideal.
You need to do a 'GetAnswers' query, inside your 'GetQuestions' query, to return all the answers for a particular question.

Something like this..

```
//'GetQuestions'
foreach($questions as $question)..

    echo $question;

    //'GetAnswers - for Question;
    foreach($answers as $answer)..

        echo $answer;

    //endAnswerLoop

//endQuestionLoop
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is it. I was thinking about it earlier but I couldn't get it to work, but I know how to do it now thanks!